# Intune shows Bitlocker policy compliant when turned off

Tags: intune, bitlocker

I have a machine where Bitlocker has been turned off, yet Intune still shows the 'Bitlocker required' policy as 'Compliant'. 
After it had been turned off, the 'Require Encryption' state changed from 'Compliant' to 'Error', yet the 'Bitlocker Required' state stayed at 'Compliant'.
This was a day ago - it has been rebooted many times since.

It's Windows 10 Pro machine that's Azure AD joined.

Does this policy not show whether Bitlocker is enabled or not?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'Require Bitlocker' policy just magically changed to 'Not Compliant'. 
I'm guessing it can take quite some time before this changes..